# Definition of submanifolds

Tags: differential-geometry, definition, smooth-manifolds, submanifold

In some books, in the definition of submanifolds, they write
\
"Let $M$ be a submanifold of $\mathbb{R^{n}}$ of dimension d if for every $x\in M$ there exists an open neighborhood such that.
$$f(U\cap M)=f(U)\cap \mathbb{R^{d}}$$
and in other book
\
Let $M$ be a submanifold of $\mathbb{R^{n}}$ of dimension d if for every $x\in M$ there exists an open neighborhood such that.
$$f(U\cap M)=f(U)\cap (\mathbb{R^{d}}\times\{0\})$$
My question is, what is the difference between these two definitions?

More precisely, why in the second definition do we add the zero and is there a difference?

Comment: You should correctly say that for each in $M$ there exists an open neighborhood $U$ and a diffeomorphism $f : U \to V \subset \mathbb R^n$ onto an open $V \subset \mathbb R^n$ such that ...

Answer (score 1):

The first book simply omits the zero, assuming that it's the "logical" way of thinking of $\mathbb R^d$ as a subset of $\mathbb R^n$. The second definition could be thought of as more precise, where you explicitly state $0\in\mathbb R^{n-d}$ to make sure you're talking about the set
$$
\{(x_1,...,x_n)\in \mathbb R^n:x_{d+1}=...=x_n=0\}
$$